# How to wait for a variable to be defined?

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to make a playbook waiting till a variable is defined?

To reduce some time in the execution of a playbook, I would like to to split it into multiple and start them at the same time. Some of them need a variables, which are defined in the other playbooks.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO it's not possible. [Global scope](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) is set only by config, environment variables and the command line.

Other variables are shared in the scope of a play. It is possible to import more playbooks into one playbook with [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook) and share variables among the playbooks. But, it's not possible to let the imported playbooks run [asynchronously](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) and let them wait for each other.

An option would be to use an external shared memory (e.g. database) and to start such playbooks separately. For example, to share variables among the playbooks at the controller, a simple ini file would do the job.

```
$ cat shared-vars.ini
[global]
```

The playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - wait_for:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/shared-vars.ini"
        search_regex: "^shared_var1\\s*=(.*)"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ini', 'shared_var1 file=shared-vars.ini') }}"
```

waits for a variable *shared_var1* in the file *shared-vars.ini*

```
$ ansible-playbook wait_for_var.yml

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************

TASK [wait_for] ********************************************************
```

Next playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - ini_file:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/shared-vars.ini"
        section: global
        option: shared_var1
        value: Test value set by declare_var.yml
```

writes the variable *shared_var1* into the file *shared-vars.ini*

```
$ ansible-playbook declare_var.yml

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************

TASK [ini_file] ********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

First playbook which was waiting for the variable continues

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Test value set by declare_var.yml"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for your explanation, but which is the problem with, that you mean: "But, it's not possible to let the imported playbooks run asynchronously and let them wait for each other."? I try doing it so, and it likes to be the way.

Comment: I mean *import_playbook* doesn't accept *async*. As a result, imported playbooks (from one central playbook to share the cached variables) can't run in parallel and wait for an event. In other words, the imported playbook must finish before another one can be imported. Don't hesitate and post the code if it likes to be the way.

Comment: Your right, importing playbooks happen only sequentially... In AWX context can be also parallelized thanks a workflow. Thanks!

Comment: AWX workflows are 2 abstraction layers above playbooks. (workflow->job template->playbook). With scripts, it's possible to build any workflow.